# Your application has stopped working, even when hooking to UnhandledExceptionHandler

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

I have added a global error handler at the AppDomain level to my C# application, by hooking into the UnhandledExceptionHandler event.

My problem is, that even though i am handling this exception, i still get the popup saying "App has stopped working".

Is this normal behaviour? Can it be turned off? or maybe it is good practice to actually have this message displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think is possible to recover the existing instance of an app when you get at that point. MSDN has no information about it and is suggested " If sufficient information about the state of the application is available, other actions may be undertaken — such as saving program data for later recovery." ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx))

It kind of makes sense to not be able to recover. If you catch an exception in the **Unhandled** ExceptionHandler it means that your application was not able to deal with it so is your last chance to log what happened (for later investigations) or save the user's data. It sounds like an architecture problem if the "unhandled" exception handler must "handle" exceptions and recover the app.

Why not recover by creating a new instance of the app? (or by using the [Restart and Recovery](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/04/20/application-recovery-and-restart-c-quick-reference.aspx) feature)

Comment: I have no problem with the application actually crashing. What i meant is, if i have a method being called when an unhandled exception occured, why do i still get that popup saying that the application crashed? i would assume the app will simply close down.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this normal behaviour?

Yes. Think about it, *where* should your code be resumed? In what state?

> Can it be turned off?

Only by handling exceptions a the appropriate point in your program, ie in the toplevel code. The UnhandledExceptionHandler is not a replacement but a diagnosis-tool for incomplete handling.

> or maybe it is good practice to actually have this message displayed?

Yes. You should log exceptions that arrive there but you've already lost control.